# Como a referência da iteração do v-for pode ser usado como parâmetro no Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Estou criando uma `TodoList` onde tenho o `editTodo()` que vai permitir alterar um item da lista, porém na declaração vi que é passado como parâmetro a referência `todo` que uso no `v-for` e fiquei com a duvida, porque não usar o `array` `todos` como parâmetro e como o método consegue visualizar esse apelido ou referência?

**Parte do componente:**

```
<div v-for="(todo,index) in todos" :key="todo.id" class="todo-item">

<div class="todo-item-left">
 <div v-if="!todo.editing" class="todo-item-label" 
    @dblclick="editTodo(todo)">{{todo.title}}
 </div>
 <input v-else class="todo-item-edit" type="text" v-model="todo.title">
```

**Método**:

```
editTodo(todo){
    todo.editing=true
}
```

Comment: Não entendi que vantagem teria passar a lista toda, se você quer editar um item específico.

Comment: E a sua segunda dúvida é sobre os detalhes de implementação do Vue? Não sei como implementaram, mas na prática cada iteração tem um escopo independente. Como se você fizesse `for (let i=0;, i<10; i++)` e passesse esse `i` para uma função no corpo do loop.